# What is the difference between class constants and class instance variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I will note that there are a lot of similarly worded questions that are distinct from what I believe I'm asking.

What is the difference between the following in terms of functionality? E.g. how do they behave with regards to inheritance?

```
class Foo
  BAR = 'Hello'
end
```

and

```
class Foo
  @bar = 'Hello'
end
```

Comment: Try it and see:)

Comment: I'm actually answering this myself :P I just wanted to post it for others who may have been wondering the same thing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Access

Constants are public by default (we're disregarding [private constants](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.4/Module.html#method-i-private_constant) here). Class instance variables are not accessible (except with stuff like `Object#instance_variable_get`, but that's typically not very good style) without a reader and/or writer method.

## Inheritance

Constants will refer to the value in the context in which they are used, not the current value of `self`. For example,

```ruby
class Foo
  BAR = 'Parent'

  def self.speak
    puts BAR
  end
end

class FooChild < Foo
  BAR = 'Child'
end

Foo.speak # Parent
FooChild.speak # Parent
```

While class instance variables are dependent on the value of `self`:

```ruby
class Foo
  @bar = 'Parent'

  def self.speak
    puts @bar
  end
end

class FooChild < Foo
  @bar = 'Child'
end

Foo.speak # Parent
FooChild.speak # Child
```

If you use an explicit reference to `self`, you can get the same behavior as constants, however:

```ruby
class Foo
  BAR = 'Parent'

  def self.speak
    puts self::BAR
  end
end

class FooChild < Foo
  BAR = 'Child'
end

Foo.speak # Parent
FooChild.speak # Child
```

Comment: "Constants are public by default" suggests that constants can be made to be something other than "public". What did you have in mind?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning, for those less versed in Ruby, that identifiers starting with a capital letter are automatically constants and can not be redefined.

Comment: @MaxFriederichs constants can be redefined. All you get is a warning for example try this `String = Integer`

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for the clarification, did not notice it was only a warning :).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I suppose I was referring to uses of the method `private_constant`. Will fix.